# What are the differences between wasm-bindgen, asm.js and Emcripten?

Tags: webpack, emscripten, webassembly, asm.js, wasm-bindgen

I'm struggling to get webpack working with a set of [WebAssembly files](https://github.com/AztecProtocol/AZTEC/tree/bf6f05940105749cdb3e172133960b086fb200f1/packages/aztec.js/src/bn128/mcl) compiled using wasm-bindgen.

Even if this could be just an [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7352) with webpack, it made me realise I don't fully grasp the differences between these quirky WebAssembly tools.

Comment: I post an answer but you may provide what exactly is the "WebAssembly module" to get a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question with a new link.

Answer (score 7):

> WebAssembly module that was compiled using wasm-bindgen and Emscripten

This doesn't make sense. You are completely mixing everything, and the issue you linked shouldn't be applied to your problem. There is no relationships between wasm-bindgen and Emscripten.

Firstly, **asm.js** was a first effort to run C/C++ (or Rust) code in a browser and is considered the precursor to WebAssembly. It is a subset of JS that C/C++ code can be compiled to. An asm.js-compiled C/C++ code can run in any browser because it is JS and will be more performant in many browsers because it is a highly-optimized subset of JS. However, asm.js is *typically* less performant than WebAssembly.

For the others, in short:

- **Emscripten** is a *C/C++* compiler toolchain for WebAssembly/asm.js.
- **wasm-bindgen** is a *Rust* binder generator to interact with JS code.